# Decrypt the Message

Tags: cipher

I tried creating a simple cipher. Don't think if there exist this type of encryption. If its not good or too easy, all suggestions are welcomed!

Encrypted Message:

> eNZWRETETTUiXVGJETUOADRYNZLSADbUOBMgLSSFCBLSBMXVWR

HINTS: Please consider hints if you really want to

Hint 1:

> Anything smaller is easy to count.

Hint 2:

> If you have two choices always choose the middle!

Hint 3:

> eGJWRKAKAIP = Hello

Hint 4: (contains two hints very strong!!)

> fPWQEWRETRYTU = Qwerty

Hope you like it if its not a stupid idea!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is

> For each 2 letters, take the letter between them in the keyboard. For letters at the end of the row in keyboard (e.g. M), the two letters will be the one next to it and the one on the other side of the row (NZ).
>
>  Not sure about the smaller letters, but they all seem to mean spaces or that the next letter is capitalized.

So the answer for eNZWRETETTUiXVGJETUOADRYNZLSADbUOBMgLSSFCBLSBMXVWR is:

> Merry Christmas In Advance

It was a pretty nice riddle, but if i may, i would definitely suggest keeping the hints to yourself and only revealing them one by one every few hours, and only if people are having trouble solving it. The hints are *very* obvious, and immediately revealing them all makes solving the puzzle rather trivial.

Also regarding the puzzle itself,

> Perhaps don't always encrypt a letter as its neighbors? In your "Hello" example, both 'L's were converted into 'KA' which is a pretty big tell. Perhaps you could encrypt one as KA and the other one as JS, either works as long as 'L' is the letter in the middle the two :)

Comment: you got it! Thanks for the suggestion and for smaller letters you can find in hints(very first hint) lol very easy:)

Comment: From the hints, I'd expect that your answer should be in sentence case and not all caps. It seems like the lowercase letter at the beginning denotes a capital letter.

Comment: @Jakob ah shoot, i completely forgot about that. Thanks, edited. Still though, every lowercase letter seem to have the same meaning - no difference between e and f and i.

Comment: Actually the lower letters are to count number of letters in word

Comment: Duh, completely missed that :P but the fact that you place them in front of every new word kinda ruins the point, doesn't it? perhaps there are better ways to position them to make it less obvious when a word starts/end. Maybe putt all the lowercase letters in front?