# Message for You:) #1

Tags: cipher

Another puzzle inspired from [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/57410/decrypt-the-message#57411) after considering suggestions. Hope its not that easy:P

Message:

> 3ccg01110525082125032107111321

Hints:

> Not Yet ;)

Comment: Are you sure [tag:alphametic] is applicable here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, this is much trickier than the previous one. Awesome!

> I'm assuming the first '3' is the number of words, ccg means the number of letters in the words (3,3,7, total 13 letters) and then followed by 26 digits, so i'm assuming each 2 digits map to a letter. So we get:
>
>  01 11 05 | 25 08 21 | 25 03 21 07 11 13 21
>
>  I noticed that the first digit is always either 0, 1 or 2. This plus your previous puzzle made me think it was another keyboard related question with 0,1,2 mapping to a row in the keyboard, but was proven wrong after a lot of unsuccessful attempts :P
>
>  The numbers range from 1 to 25 so they're likely to be numeric representation of the alphabet. Mapping 00 to A and 25 to Z we get:
>
>  BLF ZIV ZDVHLNV
>
>  Which when reversed becomes:
>
>  YOU ARE AWESOME

Gotta admit, this would've been much harder if I haven't seen the previous puzzle and read the hints/tips!

Comment: You are really awesome!! thanks for nice comments!